# Oracle query to Aurora MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, oracle, amazon-aurora

Im trying to convert Oracle JOIN query to Aurora MySQL, but getting syntax problem with (+) operators.
Can some advise or provide the right syntax query.

My Oracle Query's join looks like below:

```
select ...
from table1 A, table2 B

WHERE A.PLACE_TYP_CD = 'AREA'
        AND A.EFF_DT <= SYSDATE
        AND A.EXP_DT >= SYSDATE
AND  A.PLACE_ID = B.CHILD_LOCN_ID(+)
        AND B.LINK_REASON_TYP(+) = 'CONTAINS'
        AND B.EFF_DT(+) <= SYSDATE
        AND B.EXP_DT(+) >= SYSDATE
```

A and B being alias of tables names.

Im getting error saying :

Database error code: 1064. Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND B.LINK_REASON_TYP(+) = 'CONTAINS' AND B.EFF_DT(+) <= SYSDATE AND B.E' at line ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`(+)` is Oracle's **old**, proprietary syntax for doing an outer join.  The SQL 99 standard introduced a standard for specifying outer joins that anything written in the last, say, 15 years really ought to have been using.

This should work in any vaguely recent version of Oracle.

```
select ...
from table1 A
     left outer join table2 B
       on( A.PLACE_ID = B.CHILD_LOCN_ID
        AND B.LINK_REASON_TYP = 'CONTAINS'
        AND B.EFF_DT <= SYSDATE
        AND B.EXP_DT >= SYSDATE )
WHERE A.PLACE_TYP_CD = 'AREA'
        AND A.EFF_DT <= SYSDATE
        AND A.EXP_DT >= SYSDATE
```

If you're converting to MySQL, you'd want to replace `sysdate` with `current_timestamp` or `current_date` depending on how you are converting the column data types from Oracle to MySQL.

Comment: Unfortunaltely it didn't gave me number of records as expected .. for mysql you can use `sysdate()` instead without brackets or there is another option `now()`